Error in multiprocessing using joblib with neural prophet
I have this issue using joblib with neural prophet using TPU in kaggle :
I want to perform a multiprocessing task, and it doesn't work using TPU,
I think, but there are no errors in my code.
If anyone can help me.?
_RemoteTraceback: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 463, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 291, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 598, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 598, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_13/4008567848.py", line 22, in run_one
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/neuralprophet/forecaster.py", line 1062, in fit
    metrics_df = self._train(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/neuralprophet/forecaster.py", line 2757, in _train
    self.trainer, checkpoint_callback = utils.configure_trainer(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/neuralprophet/utils.py", line 1007, in configure_trainer
    return pl.Trainer(**config), checkpoint_callback
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/argparse.py", line 348, in insert_env_defaults
    return fn(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 513, in __init__
    self._setup_on_init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 546, in _setup_on_init
    setup._log_device_info(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/setup.py", line 166, in _log_device_info
    rank_zero_info(f"TPU available: {TPUAccelerator.is_available()}, using: {num_tpu_cores} TPU cores")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/tpu.py", line 77, in is_available
    return FabricTPUAccelerator.is_available()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning_fabric/accelerators/tpu.py", line 62, in is_available
    return bool(_XLA_AVAILABLE) and _is_device_tpu()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning_fabric/accelerators/tpu.py", line 90, in wrapper
    proc.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/process.py", line 45, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/popen_loky_posix.py", line 48, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/popen_loky_posix.py", line 128, in _launch
    pid = fork_exec(cmd_python, self._fds, env=process_obj.env)
AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'env'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[34], line 1
----> 1 p = Parallel(n_jobs=96)(jobs)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:2007, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
   2001 # The first item from the output is blank, but it makes the interpreter
   2002 # progress until it enters the Try/Except block of the generator and
   2003 # reaches the first `yield` statement. This starts the asynchronous
   2004 # dispatch of the tasks to the workers.
   2005 next(output)
-> 2007 return output if self.return_generator else list(output)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:1650, in Parallel._get_outputs(self, iterator, pre_dispatch)
   1647     yield
   1649     with self._backend.retrieval_context():
-> 1650         yield from self._retrieve()
   1652 except GeneratorExit:
   1653     # The generator has been garbage collected before being fully
   1654     # consumed. This aborts the remaining tasks if possible and warn
   1655     # the user if necessary.
   1656     self._exception = True

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:1754, in Parallel._retrieve(self)
   1747 while self._wait_retrieval():
   1748 
   1749     # If the callback thread of a worker has signaled that its task
   1750     # triggered an exception, or if the retrieval loop has raised an
   1751     # exception (e.g. `GeneratorExit`), exit the loop and surface the
   1752     # worker traceback.
   1753     if self._aborting:
-> 1754         self._raise_error_fast()
   1755         break
   1757     # If the next job is not ready for retrieval yet, we just wait for
   1758     # async callbacks to progress.

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:1789, in Parallel._raise_error_fast(self)
   1785 # If this error job exists, immediately raise the error by
   1786 # calling get_result. This job might not exists if abort has been
   1787 # called directly or if the generator is gc'ed.
   1788 if error_job is not None:
-> 1789     error_job.get_result(self.timeout)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:745, in BatchCompletionCallBack.get_result(self, timeout)
    739 backend = self.parallel._backend
    741 if backend.supports_retrieve_callback:
    742     # We assume that the result has already been retrieved by the
    743     # callback thread, and is stored internally. It's just waiting to
    744     # be returned.
--> 745     return self._return_or_raise()
    747 # For other backends, the main thread needs to run the retrieval step.
    748 try:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:763, in BatchCompletionCallBack._return_or_raise(self)
    761 try:
    762     if self.status == TASK_ERROR:
--> 763         raise self._result
    764     return self._result
    765 finally:

AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'env'

This is my code in Python using joblib, "run_one" the function who is executed in the parallel job:
def run_one(train_, region):
    print('region:', region)
    # Ignorer tous les avertissements
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
    set_log_level("ERROR")

    m = NeuralProphet(
        trend_global_local="local",
        season_global_local="local",
        yearly_seasonality="auto",
        weekly_seasonality="auto",
        daily_seasonality=False,
        epochs=40,
        n_changepoints=12
    )
    m.set_plotting_backend("plotly-static")
    m = m.add_country_holidays("MG")
    m.fit(train_, freq="D",progress=None,num_workers=20)
    
    save(m,region+'.np')
    
    future = m.make_future_dataframe(train_,periods=h)
    forecast = m.predict(future,decompose=False)
    return forecast[['ds', 'yhat1', 'ID']]

 jobs = list()
 for reg in train['region'].unique():
    train_ = train.loc[train['region'] == reg].drop(columns=['region','site'])
    jobs.append(delayed(run_one)(train_, reg))
 p = Parallel(n_jobs=96)(jobs)


I think some more information is required. Is that the whole traceback that you have shown? Which line in your code does this error occur at? What is the delayed object/function that you are adding into your jobs list?

@MattPitkin , I have updated the traceback ,"delayed" is used to wrap a function and its arguments into an object that will be executed asynchronously when called later.

did you tested joblib with simpler function (without  neural prophet)? Maybe  neural prophet needs some value which exists only in main process but not in processed created by joblib
